# How to prevent super activity's broadcast receiver from receiving broadcast messages while the child activity's receiver is registered in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

While I'm coding for my App I've come across an interesting problem which is

I've 5 activities which are derived from a common activity

```
 AppCompatActivity
        ^
        |

 CustomSuperActivity (Implemented to take advantage of the common actionbar functionalities)

        ^
        |
Activity1   Activity2 ...... Activity4       MailActivity
```

CustomSuperActivity has an implementation of the broadcast receiver Which will update the actionbar mailCount as it receives new mails from server

Here is the implementation

```
protected BroadcastReceiver mailReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        unreadMailCount ++;

        if (unreadMailCount > 0) {
            unreadMailCountTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            unreadMailCountTV.setText(String.valueOf(unreadMailCount));
        } else {
            unreadMailCountTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
};
```

And this receiver this registered and unregistered on onResume(), onPause() methods of the CustomSuperActivity respectively.

Now the problem is that the mailActivity has a chatting interface that has to be updated with newly received mails (Just like whatsapp)..

How do I implement my mailActivity so that the CustomParentActivity would not receive the broadcast while the mailActivity is on and the mailActivity's receiver receives the broadcast and updates the mail UI?

**Important:** I want to inherit mailActivity from CustomSuperActivity in order to achieve the action bar functionalities in the mailActivity

Any help or notion would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario I think the best option would be to unregister the mailReceiver in the onResume of mailActivity, re-register mailReceiver in on pause, and have a different BroadcastReceiver in your mailActivity for the receiver implementation you want to handle differently here.